# Dropbox Objective-C SDK on Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, frameworks, operating-system, dropbox

I would like to integrate Dropbox support in my application but it appears that the only SDK Dropbox has for Objective-C is for iOS. Does anyone know if the SDK can run in unison with Mac OS X considering they use the same language or is there a framework made by someone else that I can use? Been unsuccessful in my search so far.

Answer (score 3):

Dropbox just released its OS X SDK today: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox's SDK support focuses on mobile platforms, but they're all just shims over [a standard REST API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs). However, Dropbox might not approve your use of their service in your desktop application. Probably best to drop them a line and see.

Answer (score 1):

The [official answer](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=37565) from Dropbox.